# Using Tumblr Like Button with Infinite Scroll

Tags: scroll, tumblr, infinite, social-media-like

I'm trying to use the new Tumblr like buttons within Infinite Scroll (allowing your theme a like button on individual Tumblr posts from the homepage) they work for the first 15 posts of the first 'page' but then as soon as it loads another page the like button stops working. These are the instructions given from Tumblr on the Docs page:

> Function: Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(n) 
>   Description: Call this function after requesting a new page of Posts. Takes the page
>   number that was just loaded as an integer.
>
> Function: Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids([n,n,n]) 
>   Description: Request Like status for individual posts. Takes an array of post IDs.

As I'm not sure how to properly apply JQuery I'm not sure where to add these functions, here is my JS for my current theme:

```
    // MASONRY
    var $container = $('#content');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.entry',
            columnWidth: 220
        });
    });

    // INFINITE SCROLL
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '#pagination',
        nextSelector : '#pagination li a.pagination_nextlink',
        itemSelector : '.entry',
        loading: {
            img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/glziqhp/K37m9yaub/257__1_.gif'
        }
    },

    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $container.masonry(
                'appended', $newElems, true
            ); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to add a unique *post ID* to each of your posts:

```html
<div class="entry masonry-brick" id="{PostID}">...</div>
```

The documentation mentions requesting the like status once the new posts (or new page) has been appended / loaded:

```js
function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({
        opacity: 0
    });

    // Create Array of $newElems IDs
    var $newElemsIDs = $newElems.map(function () { 
        return this.id; 
    }).get();

    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $container.masonry(
            'appended', $newElems, true
        );

        // Let's just see what we have, remove console.log() if working
        console.log($newElems, $newElemsIDs);


        Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newElemsIDs);
    });
});
```

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, unfortunately this hasn't worked. Here is my Tumblr: http://andbamnan.tumblr.com If you are logged out of Tumblr/don't have an account then it works ok (I imagine because they are just turned into generic "Sign up for Tumblr" links) but once you are logged in the hearts just don't appear after the first page.

Comment: You're a champ mikedidthis, worked like a charm. Thanks buddy !

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Does the official documentation for this still exist? I can't find it anywhere