# Tumblr like button not working after infinite scroll ajax recall

Tags: api, button, tumblr, social-media-like

There are a few similar posts but they are quite out of date and Tumblr has updated the like part of the API not too long ago as far as I'm aware.

Creating a like button is as simple as 
    {LikeButton}

and this works great, but after the ajax recalls to get more posts from what would be the next page, the like button no longer works.

I have had a look at the documentation and it states that I need to implement one of the following, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? I've been trying to get this to work for hours.

[image]

I made up an example blog if this helps contribute to answering, the javascript can do the mass amount of the implementing of new images.

```
http://stackoverflowexample.tumblr.com/
```

If you need anymore info, i'll happily edit this and add what's required, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

Adapted from my previous answer here: [Using Tumblr Like Button with Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390193/using-tumblr-like-button-with-infinite-scroll/16396022#16396022)

Tumblr states we need to call one of two functions to get the **Like Status**. I would suggest the following:

> Function: Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids([n,n,n]) 
>   Description: Request Like status for individual posts. Takes an array of post IDs

Once the ajax request is successful , we should have a `data` object (containing new posts, etc).

We need to create an array of `postIDs`, which is an array containing an ID / number for each post in the `data` object. Easiest way to add the the post id is to use the theme variable `{PostID}`.

### Example

#### HTML

```
<article class="post" id="{PostID}">...</article>
```

#### jQuery Post IDs Array

```
var $newPosts   = $(data).find('.post');
var $newPostIDs = $newPosts.map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
```

#### Tumblr.LikeButton

```
Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newPostIDs);
```

#### Hints

Create  the array and call `Tumblr.LikeButton` once the ajax request is successful and in a place where you run other functions for the new Posts. This can also be done with pure javascript as using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map