# Requesting Tumblr like button status with Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I am using this [Infinite-Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com) JQuery plugin, And I am having problems with requesting the like button status for the next posts, As mentioned In [Tumblr docs](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons), I need to use `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(n)` or `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids([n,n,n])`, I've tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390193/using-tumblr-like-button-with-infinite-scroll/16396022#16396022), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789608/how-to-request-tumblr-like-button-status-after-a-new-page-is-loaded-with-infinit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390193/using-tumblr-like-button-with-infinite-scroll/16396022#16396022). And nothing works.

This is the [code](http://static.tumblr.com/is5f0mm/oBolrpvgf/infinite_scroll.txt), I need to call `Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids([n,n,n])` after the ajax return the ajax recall.

And this is the important part:

```js
$.infinitescroll = {     
        defaults      : {
                          debug           : false,
                          preload         : false,
                          nextSelector    : "div.navigation a:first",
                          loadingImg      : "http://www.infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif",
                          loadingText     : "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
                          donetext        : "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
                          navSelector     : "div.navigation",
                          contentSelector : null,           // not really a selector. :) it's whatever the method was called on..
                          extraScrollPx   : 150,
                          itemSelector    : "div.post",
                          animate         : false,
                          localMode      : false,
                          bufferPx        : 40,
                          errorCallback   : function(){}
                        }, 
        loadingImg    : undefined,
        loadingMsg    : undefined,
        container     : undefined,
        currPage      : 1,
        currDOMChunk  : null,  // defined in setup()'s load()
        isDuringAjax  : false,
        isInvalidPage : false,
        isDone        : false  // for when it goes all the way through the archive.
};
```

Comment: You need to include your code to get useful feedback.

Comment: @chloe784, Alright, I linked the code, I am not familiar with Ajax.