# Tumblr like button not working after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I am using `pjax` and `masonry` in my tumblr theme. I just figured out how to get masonry to work after clicking a pjax'd link, but now the problem is that the like button is not working anymore. Here is my code so far:

html:

```
<article class="entry" id="{PostID}">

</article>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $('#content').imagesLoaded(function(){
      $('#content').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
   });

   var $newPosts   = $(data).find('.entry');
   var $newPostIDs = $newPosts.map(function () {
     return this.id;
   }).get();

   Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newPostIDs);
});
```

Comment: `$(data).find('.entry');` what is `data` here?

Comment: I changed `div` to `article` just like what it says here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245238/tumblr-like-button-not-working-after-infinite-scroll-ajax-recall), but it is still not working.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? Can you post a link to the tumblr?

Comment: `.ajaxComplete()` is a jQuery method, not a `pjax` method. `data` is an object that should contain a collection of new elements added to the page.

Comment: My tumblr - [link](http://asphyxiatcd.tumblr.com) - Not sure if I'm getting errors in the console though? I'm not really that good in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `pjax:success`. This should give you the `data` object.

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function( event, data, status, xhr, options ) {

 $('#content').imagesLoaded(function(){
    $('#content').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
 });

 var $newPosts   = $(data).find('.entry');
 var $newPostIDs = $newPosts.map(function () {
   return this.id;
 }).get();

 Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_post_ids($newPostIDs);

});
```

Source: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I actually used `pjax:success` before to see if masonry would work, but it didn't. I guess I was missing `event, data, status, xhr, options` in the function. Thanks again!